# Why do I get the "TypeError: must be str, not float" error. I tried to convert it

Tags: python

This is the code that i'll use for now. As I run it everything is fine, Accept for when put in all the temperatures it does not print anything but gives me the error, "TypeError: must be str, not float".

```
    #temperature, kian, Thursday/March/14, working with variables. 
#this code is going to ask for a temperature in celsius then it will turn celsius temperature into fahrenheit.
celsius = float(input('what is the temperature in celsius? '))
((9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32.0)

#this code will ask for a temperature in fahrenheit and then will convert it into celsius.
fahrenheit = float(input('Enter a temperature in Fahrenheit. '))
(5.0 * (fahrenheit - 32.0)) / 9.0

#these prints should print out what was converted but there is an error of needing it to be a str not a float.
print ('the fahrenheit from celsius is, ' + celsius)
print ('the celsius from fahrenheit is, ' + fahrenheit)
```

Thank you all for the help in advance.

Comment: You need to convert `celsius` and `fahrenheit ` to string when printing

Comment: `((9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32.0)` and this statemebnt has no effect...

Answer (score -1):

```
print ('the fahrenheit from celsius is, ' + str(celsius))
print ('the celsius from fahrenheit is, ' + str(fahrenheit))
```

This would solved the problem as we concatenate strings together.

We can also do formatting via:

```
print ('the fahrenheit from celsius is %.2f ' % celsius)
print ('the celsius from fahrenheit is %.3f ' % fahrenheit)
```

to print out 2 or 3 decimals respectively.

Comment: Using string formatting would be a much better idea...

Comment: how can i delete this question.